# cannot post to facebook using facebook ios sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

i am unable to post to Facebook using Facebook ios sdk. i am receiving the following error.

"This app does not have permission to do this. to change permissions to do this. To change permissions, try logging into the app again."

```
- (void) performPublishAction:(void (^)(void)) action {
   // we defer request for permission to post to the moment of post, then we check for the permission

 if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
        // if we don't already have the permission, then we request it now
        [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                          defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                            if (!error) {
                                               action();
                                             } else if (error.fberrorCategory != FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled){
                                                 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Permission denied"
                                                                                                    message:@"Unable to get permission to post"
                                                                                                   delegate:nil
                                                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                               [alertView show];
                                            }
                                     }];
} else {
    action();
 }

}
```

i am using `Facebook` ios sample from git-hub for testing.i can successfully post to Facebook if i use some old app create on `Facebook`.i have created the app as described by the `Facebook` docs.

Comment: Have you requested the `publish_actions` permissions during your login flow?

Comment: no i am asking publish_action permissions when i want to post on facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the facebook [document v2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0) carefully, i do have similar problem.

> If your app asks for more than public_profile, email and user_friends, then it will have to be reviewed by Facebook before it can be made available to the general public. Please see our [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) on reviews for more information.

Comment: thanks, but what about the old facebook apps i had not submitted them for review but they work fine

Comment: @user2912041 i think very soon, the developers are going to get a warning messages from facebook for  submitting the app to get reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your app to Facebook at https://developers.facebook.com. Make sure to enter your app's bundle id exactly as it is in Xcode.

Comment: i have already created an app on facebook, i can login through my app but cannot post anything